# Media Projection resets ARCore session

Tags: arcore, capacitor, android-mediaprojection

I am working on an Ionic project where I am using ARCore via a custom plug-in. In the webview I am rendering the 3D object and receiving ARCore pose info from native android per frame.

Now I have a requirement to capture the ARCore session along with 3D objects rendered in the webview. I am using Media Projection to capture the screen. To start screen capture user needs to allow the permission, once the user gave the permission, my ARCore session is being reset after I create the MediaProjection object. As per the requirement once user choose to place the object in AR he will start recording the screen, but due to this session reset, requirement is breaking.

I am using a foreground service to get the screen capture permission (Firing an activity from service & close it after the permission request). I need a way to avoid this ARSession reset. I tried searching for relation between the MediaProjection service and ARCore didn't find any. Requesting you for any suggestion or direction which I should take on..

Thank you